# What 3D rendering technic/algorithm is most effective to draw beams by edges?

Tags: c#, algorithm, 3d, render

I'm trying to construct a program in C# that generates a 3D model of a structure composed of beams, and then creates some views of the object (front, side, top and isometric).

As I don't need to draw surfaces (the edges are enough), I've been calculating each line to draw, and then do it with

```
GraphicObject.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

This worked fine so far, but as I get adding parts to the structure, the refresh of `GraphicObject` takes too much time. So I'm getting into line visibility check to reduce the amount of lines to draw.

I've searched Wikipedia and some PDFs on the subject, but all I found is oriented by surfaces. So my question: **Is there a simplified algorithm to check visibility of object edges, or should i go for a different approach, like considering surfaces?**

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks for your help.

Additional notes/questions:

My current approach:

- calculate every beam in a local axis (all vertices)

  - => move them to their global position
  - => create a list with pairs of points (projected and scaled to the view)
  - => `GraphicObject.DrawLine` the list of point pairs)
- would the whole thing be faster if I'd calculate the view by pixels rather than using the `DrawLine` method?

Screenshots follow with the type of structure it's going to do (not fully complete yet):

- Structure view

[image: structure view]

- Structure detail

[image: structure detail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to improve the performance.
a) switch the computation to the graphics card.
b) Use a kd-tree or some other similar data structure to quickly remove the non visible edges.

Here's more details:
For a), a lot of you computations are multiplying many vertices (vectors of length 3) by some matrix. The CPUs are slow because they only do a couple of these operations at a time. Switch to a GPU, for example using CUDA, which will allow you to do them more in parallel, with better memory access infrastructure. You can also use OpenGL/DirectX/Vulkan or whatever to render the lines themselves to skip having to get the results back from the graphics card and whatever other hiccups get introduced by windows code/libraries. This will help in almost all cases to improve performance.

For b), it only helps when you are not looking at the entire scene (in that case you really need to draw everything). In this cases you can store you scene in a kd-tree or some other data structure and use it to quickly remove things that are for sure outside of the view area. You usually need to intersect some cuboid with a pyramid/fustrum so there's more math involved.

As a compromise that should help in a large scenes where you want to see everything you can consider adjusting the level of detail. From your example, the read beans across are composed of 8 or so components. If you are far enough you are not going to be able to distinguish the 8, so just draw one. This will work great if you have a large number of rounded edges as you can simplify a lot of them.